# Tag sort algorithm - can't get mine to work

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tags

I found a java example of a tag sort algorithm online, and I decided to implement it into my code.

I need a non-destructive way of sorting an array, so using a separate array as an index for the order of the sort seems like the way to go.

This is the code I found:

```
int n = persons.length;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (persons[tag[i]].getSalary() >
            persons[tag[j]].getSalary())
        {
            int temp = tag[i];
            tag[i] = tag[j];
            tag[j] = temp;
        }
   }
}
```

So I adapted it into this: (not any known scripting language, from an adventure game engine)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < 5; j++)
  {
    if (testOriginal[testOrdered[i]] > testOriginal[testOrdered[j]])
    {
      int temp = testOrdered[i];
      testOrdered[i] = testOrdered[j];
      testOrdered[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

But when the feed in the sequence [6, 5, 3, 8, 1] (for example), it spits out "42103", which is obviously incorrect. It should be "32140". I followed the logic of the function on paper and got the same result.

However, when I run the java version, it works perfectly every time.

Can someone help me see where I'm going wrong? I know I must be making some dumb mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To me it seems correct. Or perhaps you inverted the index strings ( "42103" seems correct)

Comment: Edit: I'm an idiot. I just figured it out. It's been correct all along, I was just reading the "42103" completely wrong. Sorry!